# Why does $E\exp(\theta X_i)<\infty$ imply that $EX_i^+<\infty$

Tags: probability-theory, large-deviation-theory

> Why does $E\exp(\theta X_i)<\infty$ imply that $EX_i^+<\infty$ for $\theta>0$?

Is it because of: $\exp(\theta X_i)\ge|1\pm\theta X_i|$, on $\theta X_i>-1$

So then $E\exp(\theta X_i)\ge E|1+\theta X_i|,\quad E\exp(\theta X_i)\ge E|1-\theta X_i|$ and both imply $E|\theta X_i|<\infty$ on $\theta X_i>-1$ do you agree ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be a real number.

1. If $x < 0$, then $\theta \cdot x^+ = 0 \leq e^{\theta x}$
2. If $x \geq 0$, then using $e^y \geq 1+y$ for all $y$, we get $\theta x^+ \leq 1 + \theta x^+ \leq e^{\theta x^+} = e^{\theta x}$.

We use this to derive
$$
\Bbb{E}(\theta \cdot  X_i^+ ) \leq \Bbb{E} e^{\theta X_i} < \infty,
$$
which easily implies $\Bbb{E}(X_i^+) < \infty$.

Comment: Thanks, but the same is not valid for $\theta X^-_i$, right ? since the first point fails, but is there another way to bound it ?

Comment: The claim is false for $X_{i}^-$. To see this, consider a probability measure on $\Bbb{N}$ with $\Bbb{P}(\{n\}) = \frac{c}{n^2}$ for all $n$ and let $X(n) := -n$. Then $\Bbb{E}X_- = -c \sum_n \frac{n}{n^2} = -\infty$, but $\Bbb{E}e^X = c \sum_n \frac{e^{-cn}}{n^2} \leq \sum_n \frac{c}{n^2} = 1 < \infty$.